# Smack XMPP not rejoin on login after more then two minutes

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

I am using `smack-android:4.2.0` for creating a simple chat app for groups. I have created MUC chatroom every thing including subscription is working just fine. If I logout and then login again in the time span of 2minutes then the user automatically join the groups but if user login after 2 minutes then the user can't rejoin any group.

Here is how I am creating group

```
public void creatGroupTaskXMPP(String groupImageServerPath , String groupname , String userids) {
    try
    {
        if(connection.isAuthenticated())
        {
            MyPreferences myPreferences = new MyPreferences(context);
            MultiUserChat chatRoom = MyXMPP.multiUserChatManager.getMultiUserChat(MyXMPP.createEntityBareJID(myPreferences.getUSER_ID() + "_" + CommonMethods.getCurrentGMTTime(0) + "@conference."
                + context.getString(R.string.server)));

            MyXMPP.multiUserChatManager.setAutoJoinOnReconnect(true);

            MultiUserChat.MucCreateConfigFormHandle myRoom = chatRoom.createOrJoin(Resourcepart.from(AppConstants.csUserID));

            if (myRoom != null) {

                chatRoom.addMessageListener(multiChatMsgListener);
                chatRoom.addParticipantStatusListener(mChatParticipantStatusListener);
                chatRoom.addParticipantListener(MCPresenceListener);
                chatRoom.addPresenceInterceptor(MCPresenceListener);

                Form form = chatRoom.getConfigurationForm().createAnswerForm();
                form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomname", groupname);
                form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
                form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_allow_subscription", true);
                form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_mam", true);

                List<Affiliate> affiliates = chatRoom.getOwners();

                chatRoom.sendConfigurationForm(form);

                addSubscription(chatRoom);

                ArrayList<EntityBareJid> JabberIdList = new ArrayList<EntityBareJid>();

                String str[] = userids.split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
                {
                    if(userids != null && userids.length() > 0)
                        JabberIdList.add(createEntityBareJID(userids + "@" + context.getString(R.string.server)));
                }

                JSONObject jsonObject = createJsonForInvite(str , groupImageServerPath );

                for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
                chatRoom.invite(createEntityBareJID(str[i] + "@" + context.getString(R.string.server)), jsonObject.toString());
                String room_Id[] = chatRoom.getRoom().toString().split("@");
                CreatGroup.updateDB(jsonObject , room_Id[0]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(login())
            {
                creatGroupTaskXMPP(groupImageServerPath , groupname, userids);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ed)
    {
        ed.printStackTrace();
        Logger.errorLog("Group Crate Exception Message = " + ed.getMessage());
    }

}
```

and this is my subscription method

```
public void addSubscription(MultiUserChat chatRoom)
{
    String csSubId = AppConstants.csUserID + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;


    try
    {
        IQ iq = new IQ("subscribe", "urn:xmpp:mucsub:0") {
            @Override
            protected IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder getIQChildElementBuilder(IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder xml)
            {
                String csXMLString = xml.toString();

                //xml.xmlnsAttribute();

                xml.attribute("nick", AppConstants.csUserID);
                xml.attribute("password", "");
                xml.rightAngleBracket();

                xml.halfOpenElement("event");
                xml.attribute("node", "urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages");
                xml.closeEmptyElement();

                xml.halfOpenElement("event");
                xml.attribute("node", "urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:affiliations");
                xml.closeEmptyElement();

                xml.halfOpenElement("event");
                xml.attribute("node", "urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:subject");
                xml.closeEmptyElement();

                xml.halfOpenElement("event");
                xml.attribute("node", "urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:config");
                xml.closeEmptyElement();

                xml.halfOpenElement("event");
                xml.attribute("node", "urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:presence");
                xml.closeEmptyElement();

                xml.halfOpenElement("event");
                xml.attribute("node", "urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:system");
                xml.closeEmptyElement();

                //xml.closeElement("subscribe");
                csXMLString = xml.toString();

                return xml;
            }
        };


        iq.setFrom(AppConstants.csEJabberedId);
        iq.setTo(chatRoom.getRoom());
        iq.setStanzaId(StanzaIdUtil.newStanzaId());
        iq.setType(IQ.Type.set);

        String csStanzaXML = iq.toString();

        connection.createStanzaCollectorAndSend(iq).nextResultOrThrow();
        //sendStanza(iq);
    }
    catch (Exception ed)
    {
        ed.printStackTrace();
        Logger.errorLog("Group Crate Exception Message = " + ed.getMessage());
    }
    //IQElement iqElement = new IQElement(AppConstants.appContact.csEJabberedId, chatRoom.getRoom(), "set", csSubId);


    // iqElement.addCustomElement(subscribeElement);

    //String responseString = iqElement.toXML().toString();

    //chatRoom.sendMessage(responseString);
}
```

I have checked some answers on SO but all of them are for older versions or not relevant.

Over the internet, some threads seem to answer it like it is not possible to rejoin the older rooms but in IOS it is possible. I hope there will be a same feature for Android too.

Thanks.

Comment: have you stored the room jid somewhere locally?

Comment: @SarthakMittal yes

Comment: But I don't want to rejoin all the groups after every login.

Comment: sadly, this is the default implementation. one workaround would be to tweak your server to keep the users connected to group.

Comment: But in IOS you don't need to rejoin on every login.

Comment: which application are you talking about?

Comment: in smack XMPP IOS.

Comment: smack has no support for iOS yet, can u provide the link, which lib r u talking about?

Comment: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/ this one

Comment: this: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework is not smack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152026/discussion-between-sarthak-mittal-and-syeda-zunairah).